# Did not create model for user table. is it mandatory for order table?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm a newbie in django and doing my very first food delivery website. I've not created any model for user auth table but created model for my menu table. now i want to create a model for order table where i want to keep both menu id and user id as foreign key.. is it possible any way or i must create a model for user table also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django is already have a User model ready for you , you can use it as below:

```
#first import the user model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# then add it as a ForeignKey
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack OverFlow.

If you are starting a new project, it is better to inherit `AbstractUser` and use custom user model. This way it will be easier to customize your user model like adding fields, methods, customizing Django admin, etc.

Full reference here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

For this you will have to create a custom user model and point **AUTH_USER_MODEL** to the model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Then in **settings.py**
*(Assuming user model is in user_app app*:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL="user_app.user"
```

Comment: Thanks.. I'll be using this as well